# Excel vba - changing format to date, but can't sort it

Tags: vba, excel

I changed the format of range of cells to date like this: `.NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy"`. But when I right click those cells I get that format is custom (and its in dd.mm.yyyy), and when I try to sort that range, I can't sort it Oldest To Newest, just A-Z.

And second question. What is the difference in lines  `.NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy;@"` and `.NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy"`

Comment: Depending on your version of excel, but I don't think using a period is recognised as dates. What if you custom format `"dd/mm/yyyy"`? Also the `;@` is to do with regional based dates, adding `;@` keeps the dates fixed how you set them, and they won't change for example in america where they use the mm/dd/yyyy format.

Comment: The `@` part is for text formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that your data is not recognized as dates, but as strings.

You can check this for example by replacing the month-part of the formatting string with three mmm (`.NumberFormat = "dd.mmm.yyyy"`). If that results in displaying the name of the month rather than the number, you have a date. Else Excel sees only text strings, and of course this can be sorted only as strings.

In case you have strings, maybe a helper column could help you, containing a formula to convert the string into date.

Comment: Yes, that was the case. Thanks